# Efficient Numpy Array Multiplication and Reshaping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a simpler way to get this done?

Consider that I have an array of data points of length `m` - for instance, the amount of rain that accumulated at a weather station over the course of a single day for `m` many days. Now, we want to add `n` many small, semi-random perturbations to each day's data to create `m * n` many perturbed observations. Furthermore, we can divide the day into `q` many periods, and we have an estimate of the proportion of any day's rain that accumulates in each of those periods; we are assuming that the proportion of rain that accumulates during any period is not dependent on the day.

So I have an array of the daily observations of length `m`, **(EDIT: length `n` was fixed to length `m`)** which when perturbed becomes an array of shape `[m,n]`, and an an array of period proportions of length `q`. What I want now is an array of shape `[n,m*q]` with one row for each perturbation, where each row is the concatenation of the "period-expanded" perturbed estimates of the daily rainfall observations.

As an example, we can define a toy set of data:

```
import numpy as np

m = 4
n = 3
q = 5

X = np.arange(m*n).reshape(m,n)
E = (np.arange(1,m*n + 1) /10).reshape(m,n)
X = X - E

Y = np.arange(1,q)
np.random.shuffle(Y)
Y = Y / np.sum(np.arange(1,q))

print(f'X : \n{X}')
print(f'Y : \n{Y}')
```

which gives us

```
X : 
[[-0.1  0.8  1.7]
 [ 2.6  3.5  4.4]
 [ 5.3  6.2  7.1]
 [ 8.   8.9  9.8]]
Y : 
[0.2 0.3 0.1 0.4]
```

My solution is :

```
res = (X[:,:,np.newaxis] * Y[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:]).transpose(1,0,2).reshape(X.shape[1],-1)
print(f'res : \n{res}')
```

which gives us the appropriate answer :

```
res : 
[[-0.02 -0.03 -0.01 -0.04  0.52  0.78  0.26  1.04  1.06  1.59  0.53  2.12
   1.6   2.4   0.8   3.2 ]
 [ 0.16  0.24  0.08  0.32  0.7   1.05  0.35  1.4   1.24  1.86  0.62  2.48
   1.78  2.67  0.89  3.56]
 [ 0.34  0.51  0.17  0.68  0.88  1.32  0.44  1.76  1.42  2.13  0.71  2.84
   1.96  2.94  0.98  3.92]]
```

Admittedly it would be easier to expand the observatons first and then randomly perturb, but the order of operations is a hard requirement on this particular problem: the observations must first be perturbed then the perturbed observations must be expanded and concatenated.

Comment: Though the code certainly isn't too easy to follow, it's probably about as computationally efficient as you'll get since you don't dip down into pure Python anywhere.

Comment: I've read this twice now, and I still don't understand the `Y` array of so-called "period proportions of length `q`". What does it represent? In your example, what is the meaning of the values `[0.2, 0.3, ...]`?  Also, the example of `X` is confusing. It may be easier for us to understand if you simply used `np.random.seed(0)` or similar to ensure a reproducible example, and then make your array of measurements and the one for perturbations as actual random arrays, etc.